# Redirection to pool

Tags: mining-pools, connection

dear friends. Due that my ISP blocks connection to pools i need to make a redirection via VPS that i has to a mining pool. I am very bad at networking and hardly can imagine how can i accomplish this. Let's be more specific.

The miner i am using is Claymore CryptoNote CPU Miner v3.5 Beta.

IP Address of my VPS is **104.198.203.30**

My VPS system is

```
uname -a
Linux instance-11 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.43-2 (2017-04-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Questions:

1. What do i enter in my bat file to start miner under -o option ?
2. What commands do i need to enter on my VPS to forward all mining packets to a dwarf pool that has following address: **xmr-usa.dwarfpool.com:10000**

I need my miner to connect to dwarf pool via ssh or any other method through VPS(104.198.203.30). I got root access to my VPS machine. For my ISP it should look like i am sending packages to **104.198.203.30** and not dwarf pool.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: This may be more on-topic for a general purpose networking site, since VPN forwarding isn't really specific to Bitcoin at all.  But you should say what OS you are using on your mining system.  The simplest approach may be to set up an ssh tunnel, e.g. the `-L` option to `ssh`.

Comment: i am using windows server 2016 on mining machine. sorry for placing it here.

Comment: @GavGav, I think you should edit your question so you do not expose your IP address in public.

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the same case, I'm mining at my lab.

The simple way :

If your mining computer is under Linux, and you have an VPS, simply do that on your  mining computer :

```
ssh user@yourvpsip -C -L 123:yourpool.com:123
```

(where 123 is the port of the pool)

Then, configure your mining software to listen on 127.0.0.1:123
(dont change 127.0.0.1, but change 123 to the same port as precedent)
It's like the pool is on your computer :)

And, better, add  keepalive option by adding this :

```
-o TCPKeepAlive=yes -o ServerAliveInterval=5
```

For exemple, for me it's :

```
ssh -L 5555:mine.xxx-pool.com:5555 xerces@xxx.xxx.net -C -o TCPKeepAlive=yes -o ServerAliveInterval=5
```

For you :

```
ssh -L 10000:xmr-usa.dwarfpool.com:10000: youruser@104.198.203.30 -C -o TCPKeepAlive=yes -o ServerAliveInterval=5
```

The more complicated but more effective way is using autossh, so the tunnel can keeps itself open.

Comment: Since the machine is running Windows, it does not have SSH preinstalled. You can either create an ssh tunnel through Putty with a GUI or you can get [OpenSSH for Powershell](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH) for cli